# How to update input value react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a list and edit button when user click edit button opening a new modal. I want to  auto populate the selected username mail etc. Server side response is {this.test.name} i give him to input value to auto populate but when user click edit button ı can see the name but ı couldnt change the input how do ı do that ?
Code :

```
<div className = "form__group field">
    <input type="input" className="form__field" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" value={this.test.name}  />
    <label htmlFor="name" className="form__label">Adı-Soyadı</label>
</div>
```

Comment: <div className="form__group field">
    <input type="input" className="form__field" placeholder="Name" name="name" id="name" value={this.test.name}  />
    <label htmlFor="name" className="form__label">Adı-Soyadı</label>
</div>

Comment: Did you try out what I added in the comments? Consider giving some feedback, greetings

Answer (score 2):

If you are using hooks, you could do something like this:

```js
import { useState } from "react"; // import useState

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState(""); // useState hook

  // handle change event
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action
    setName(e.target.value); // set name to e.target.value (event)
  };

  // render
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={name} type="text" onChange={handleChange}></input>
      <p>{name}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

First, we `import` the `useState()` hook to be able to use it, then we use it to store the state for the name value, you can give it an initial value of an empty string (`""`). In the `handleChange()` function, we prevent the default action and set the state to `e.target.value`, this is the input value passed by the event (as `(e)`). Every time the input changes, the state will update and the page will re-render.

You could check out my sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-joliot-jr7q4?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I am using react v0.14 ı cant use useState but thank you other solutions didnt work for me. i did the same thing but ı couldnt change

Comment: Could you try adding `onChange={handleChange}` in your `<input>` tag and copy the handleChange function I added above? Then replace `setName(...)` by `setState({name: e.target.value})` or with what properties the state has.

Comment: For checking if the values are correctly passed, you could try logging the event by adding `console.log(e.target.value)` in the `handleChange()` function.

Answer (score 1):

1. Keep the name in the state:

```js
this.state = {
    name: '',
}
```

(setState when you have it, if you retrieve it only on mount)

2. Pass value={this.state.name} to the input.
3. Pass onChange={handleNameChange} to the input.

```js
const handeNameChange = (e) => { 
    setState({ name: e.target.value });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change that input value because you've set the value to `this.test.name` and did not defined an `onChange` handler. So what you should do is create a state for your input field and on `componentDidMount`, populate this state with data from server.

Then on your input field

```
this.state = {
  val: ''
}

<input value={this.test.name}  onChange={e => setState({val: e.target.value})}/>
```

Maybe there can be a syntax error, because I am used to work with hooks now, but that's pretty much the gist of it

Answer (score 0):

```
//Declare your states
const [name,setName] = useState('')
const [test,setTest] = useState('')

// fetch the data with use effect
useEffect(() =>{
const fetch = async () =>{
const res = await fetch('http://yourUrl.com')
const data = await res.json()
setTest(test)
}}
fetch()
},[test])

// use another useEffect hook to set the input value
// using setTimeout 
useEffect(() =>{
setTimeout(()=>{
setName(test.name)
.... // rest of the states, if you have more
}, 1000}
},[name]) //Don't forget to set the dependency array
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).